# How to create app bar that take all space of appbar+colorPrimeryDark area

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appbar

Trying to create app bar that take all the space of appbar + space of colorPrimeryDark like screenshot given below [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** For that first you need to create a theme as follows:

```
<!-- Make the status bar traslucent -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
```

**Step 2:** Make a method which would be getting `Status bar` height:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Step 3:** Call the method from `onCreate()` method of `Activity` and change the color of the `Status bar` as you desire:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

       // Retrieve the AppCompact Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       // Set the padding to match the Status Bar height
        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);

      // create our manager instance after the content view is set
       SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
     // enable status bar tint
       tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    // enable navigation bar tint
       tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
   // set the transparent color of the status bar, 20% darker
      tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#20000000"));
    }
```

Follow the above steps and you would get your status bar transparent and you can add image or color to background.